Grid Bool Values no checkmarks
I am using C# DevExpress Blazor UI (relative new) and build a Grid, which is bound to a DataTable. This works, but I have some Boolean Values in there, which are automatically shown as HUGE checkmarks. How can I change the data type so that the values are shown as True/False 1/0 and not as checkmarks
And how you may see on the picture is this checkmark really huge and unpractical. If I want to use it, how can I customize it and make it smaller?
So in short: how can I achieve that Boolean Values are shown as true/false and not as huge checkmarks in my DevExpress Blazor Grid
<DxGrid Data="@data">
    <Columns>
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="PERSON_USERNAME" />
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="PERSON_LASTNAME" />
        <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="PERSON_LOCKED" />
    </Columns>
</DxGrid>

How its in the Datatable
How its shown on the compiled Website
I already searched all of the documentation of DevExpress but found nothing (and the whole thing is very confusing) and I searched the whole internet and Youtube but all I found were videos from devexpress directly but sometimes just bad explained and nothing to do with my problem
